# Посчитать сумму выпадающих списков и чекбоксов с условием

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, checkbox

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста!

```
    <h2>Рассчет стоимости</h2>

<label for="model">Выберите модель кровати</label>
   <select name="model_krovat" id="model" class="form-control">
   <option value="6300">Белава</option>
   <option value="7000">Чердак</option>
</select>

<label for="shirina">Выберите ширину</label>

<select class="form-control" name="shirina_krovat" id="shirina">
   <option value="500">900</option>
   <option value="1000">1000</option>
   <option value="1000">1100</option>
</select>

<label for="dlina">Выберите длину</label>

<select class="form-control" name="dlina_krovat" id="dlina">
   <option value="550">1900</option>
   <option value="1000">2000</option>
   <option value="1000">2100</option>
</select>

<label for="visota">Выберите высоту</label>

<select name="visota_krovat" id="visota" class="form-control">
   <option value="600">1600</option>
   <option value="1000">1700</option>
   <option value="1000">1800</option>
</select>

<h4>Стоимость</h4
```

> Нужно вывести сумму выбранных select из выпадающего списка и чекбоксов при нажатии с условиями.
>   Выбираем модель Белава:summa=6300;
>   выбираем ширину-900 к summa прибавляем 500 из value="500";
>   выбираем длину-1900 к summa прибавляем 550 из value="500";
>   выбираем длину-1900 к summa прибавляем 600 из value="500";
>   Должно вывести summa=7950 руб

```
<p class="price">
  <span id="final_price">0</span> Руб.
</p>

<label for="yslygi">Верхняя торцевая перегородка</label>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="calc()" id="yslygi" name="peregorodka" />
```

> Если нажат чекбокс1:
>   если ширина=900, то к summa прибавляем 100; (summa=7950 руб+100=8050)
>   если ширина=1000, то к summa прибавляем 100;
>   если длина=1900,  то к summa прибавляем 100;
>   если длина=2000,  то к summa прибавляем 200; 
>   если высота=1600,  то к summa прибавляем 100;
>   если высота=1700,  то к summa прибавляем 200;

```
<label for="yslygi2">Борта у стены</label>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="calc()" id="yslygi2" name="bort" />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: извините за корявый код(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подозреваю, что описание формул содержит опечатки и/или неполное, поэтому подправьте код функции расчета под реальные нужды уже сами.

```js
function calculate() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('select').each(function() {
    sum += parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  if ($("#yslygi").is(':checked')) {
    if ($('#shirina').val() == "500" || $('#shirina').val() == "1000") sum += 100;
    if ($('#dlina').val() == "550") sum += 100;
    if ($('#dlina').val() == "1000") sum += 200;
    if ($('#visota').val() == "600") sum += 100;
    if ($('#visota').val() == "1000") sum += 200;
  }
  $('#final_price').html(sum);
}
$('select,input').change(function() {
  calculate();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="model">Выберите модель кровати</label>
<select name="model_krovat" id="model" class="form-control">
    <option value="6300">Белава</option>
    <option value="7000">Чердак</option>
</select>
<label for="shirina">Выберите ширину</label><br>
<select class="form-control" name="shirina_krovat" id="shirina">
    <option value="500">900</option>
    <option value="1000">1000</option>
    <option value="1000">1100</option>
</select>
<label for="dlina">Выберите длину</label><br>
<select class="form-control" name="dlina_krovat" id="dlina">
    <option value="550">1900</option>
    <option value="1000">2000</option>
    <option value="1000">2100</option>
</select>
<br>
<label for="visota">Выберите высоту</label>
<select name="visota_krovat" id="visota" class="form-control">
     <option value="600">1600</option>
     <option value="1000">1700</option>
     <option value="1000">1800</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<h4>Стоимость</h4>
<p class="price">
  <span id="final_price">0</span> Руб.
</p>
<label for="yslygi">Верхняя торцевая перегородка</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="yslygi" name="peregorodka" />???<br/>
<label for="yslygi2">Борта у стены</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="yslygi2" name="bort" />???
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!Очень выручили!Главное формула работает.

Comment: @Лиана если ответ подходит в качестве решения проблемы - не забывайте принять как верный :)

Comment: Подскажите,где принять?

Comment: @Лиана галочка слева от ответа

Comment: Прошу прощения, на странице Стоимость = 0 можно узнать как задать значение Стоимость = 3600?

Comment: @Лиана $(‘#final_price’).html(‘3600’) а зачем именно 3600? Наверное вам нужно просто функцию пересчитать при загрузке страницы

Comment: извините не правильно задала вопрос:в выпадающем списке  <option  selected="selected"  value="6300">Белава</option> выбрана Белава и нужно что бы отображалась в стоимости его значение - 6300.

Comment: @Лиана так это ж некорректные данные, нужно выводить с подсчетом по всем полям

Comment: хорошо поняла.Спасибо!

Comment: Извините, но у меня появился еще один вопрос.

Comment: Извините, но у меня появился еще один вопрос. При выборе длины есть option с одинаковыми значениями value="550", и при нажатии на один чекбокс к сумме он прибавляет оба значения 100 и 200:  if ($('#dlina').val() == "550") sum += 100;
    if ($('#dlina').val() == "550") sum += 200; Как их разделить?

Comment: @Лиана очевидно, дать им разные value

Comment: хорошо,спасибо!

Comment: Подскажите,пожалуйста, как напротив checkbox "Верхняя торцевая перегородка ???"  вместо ??? выводилось его значение при нажатии на него

Comment: @Лиана это уже больше подходит под отдельный вопрос

Comment: поняла,благодарю.